# Remove some HTML Tags using RegEx MVC

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm sending an email by pressing a button which converts the entire View into a String and this String is used as the body of the email.

But when the mail arrives, the View buttons appear, which I try to eliminate with RegEx but it doesn't work

How can I remove those tags from the string?

Here's my view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcInventory.TB_RS_PROD>
@{

}
<html>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>ID PRODUCT</td>
        <td>PRODUCT NAME</td>
        <td>QUIANTITY</td>
        <td>DATE</td>
        <td>STATUS</td>
        <td>EMAIL</td>
        <td>EMAIL 2</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>@item.IDPROD</td>
           <td>@item.PROD_NAME</td>
           <td>@item.QUANTITY</td>
           <td>@item.UPDATE_DATE</td>
           <td>@item.STATUS</td>
           <td>@item.EMAIL</td>
           <td>@item.EMAIL2</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SendEmail","Home")'">Send Email</button>
</html>
```

String Writer code:

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
}
```

At last the RenderPartialViewToString's call

```
var htmlp = RenderPartialViewToString("~/Views/ActionApprovers/Action.cshtml", TempData["email-act"]);
var allowtag = new Regex(@"(</?[^(p|ol|ul|li|span|i|b|br|table|tr|td)]/?>)");
htmlp = allowtag.Replace(htmlp, "");
```

Comment: `[^(p|ol|ul|li|span|i|b|br|table|tr|td)]` is a wrong pattern, a negated character class only matches one char, you can't use it to match any text but some char sequence(s).

Comment: In this case, what do you recommend me to do in order to remove <button> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several post to I recommend doing the following method for the tags that you want to keep and delete

```
    string acceptable = "p|a|tr|td|table|html"; //Tags that are a-okay to display
    string stringPattern = @"</?(?(?=" + acceptable + @")notag|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+=?(?:(["",']?).*?\1?)?)*\s*/?>";
    htmlp = Regex.Replace(htmlp, stringPattern, "");
```